# Using ruamel.yaml to print out a list with individual elements singlequoted?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have a dictionary with a few lists(contains a # of strings).

Example List:

```
hosts = ['199.168.1.100:1000', '199.168.1.101:1000']
```

When I try to print this out using ruamel.yaml, the elements show up as

```
hosts:
- 199.168.1.100:1000
- 199.168.1.101:1000
```

I want the results to be

```
hosts:
- '199.168.1.100:1000'
- '199.168.1.101:1000'
```

So I traversed through the list and created a new list with each element being a ruamel SingleQuotedString

```
S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString

new_list = []
for e in hosts:
   new_list.append(S(e))

hosts = new_list
```

When I print this out, I still end up printing the "hosts" list without any quotes. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your program is incomplete, and the error is in the part you are not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I assume you mean dumping to YAML when you indicate printing.

Your approach is in principle correct, as using the "global"

```
 yaml.default_style = "'"
```

would also get the key `hosts` quoted, and that is not what you
want. Maybe you are not reassigning `hosts` to the actual datastructure that 
you are dumping, because `hosts` is just the value of the key value pair you
are dumpiong.

The following:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

data = dict(hosts = [S(x) for x in ['199.168.1.100:1000', '199.168.1.101:1000']])
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

will give what you want without problem:

```
hosts:
- '199.168.1.100:1000'
- '199.168.1.101:1000'
```

Comment: Thank you @Anthon, that sorted out my issue!